# OnTouchListener on LinearLayout that is behind buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I am working on an Android application using C# in Xamarin. In my axml file, I have a LinearLayout with a certain ID that I have assigned a onTouchListener to. The problem is that as long as the buttons I have in my design are on top of the linearLayout, the onTouchListener is never triggered. If I set one of the buttons to invisible, then it works.

Is it possible to still have the onTouchListener react even though there are Controls in the way?

This is my axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I set the onTouchlistener for the linearLayout:

```
LinearLayout linLay = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LinearLayout1);
linLay.SetOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(this));
```

This is a custom touch listener class:

```
    public class MyTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnTouchListener
    {
    Context activityContext;

    public MyTouchListener(Context ac)
    {
        activityContext = ac;
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;

        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            // do stuff

            x = e.GetX();
            y = e.GetY();

            Toast.MakeText(activityContext, x.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();


            return true;
        }
        //if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        //{
        //    // do other stuff
        //    return true;
        //}
        return true;
    }
}
```

And finally, this is how I set up the button click listener:

```
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button.Click += (s,e) =>
        {
            //int i = count % s.Count;
            //if(i > 28)
            //    Toast.MakeText(this, button.GetX().ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();

            button.Text = string.Format("{0}", count++);

        };
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to intercept the touch event. In order to do that you have to subclass `LinearLayout` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent()`:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "onTouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.your.package.MyLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.your.package.MyLinearLayout>
```

Now any touch event on the layout will be handled by your custom `MyLinearLayout`.

Comment: Thank you alot for taking the time to answer. I am sorry if I did not make this clear in the question, but I am using Xamarin and C# for this. Your code is Java right? I figured it would be enough to use the tagging system. My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend (inherent) the parent linear layout so that you can intercept touch events from the nested children layouts.  Override these two methods to receive touches from the children. Then in your xml you will add "myCustomLinearLayout" or whatever you name the your custom linear layout class.  It should be pretty similar in C# / Xamarin.

```
@Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
     return true; // With this i tell my layout to consume all the touch events from its childs
  }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    // Log.d(TAG, String.format("ACTION_DOWN | x:%s y:%s", 
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    //Log.d(TAG, String.format("ACTION_MOVE | x:%s y:%s", 
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: LinearLayout linLay = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LinearLayout1);
linLay.SetOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener(this));

Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
And then I have a button.Click += (s, e) => { ... };

What I want to accomplish is to both have a OnTouchListener on the LinearLayout at the same time as I have a button click event listener on the buttons in front of it.

Comment: If you voted down the question, please have a look at it now as I have updated and made it more clear, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: It wasn't me! I'll take another look.

Comment: See the other persons answer above mine, since you have nested view groups, the child views aren't passing the touch event onto your parent layout.  See the android documentation for more details on how to handle this. https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#intercept